# Sort sheet according to birthday date without considering the year of a date

Tags: arrays, date, sorting, google-sheets, google-query-language

I am trying to sort sheet according to birthday date, the closest birthday should go in first row, and the last go to the end and so on, to do this it should only consider the day and month without taking into account the year for the sorting, all this by using the query function since the data is being queried from another sheet.

I have tried using the following

```
=SORT(QUERY('Sheet1'!A2:Q, "SELECT * "),6,FALSE)
```

but it is not working, i have also tried formatting the data to show only day and month via google sheets custom date and time, and still only hides the year but for sorting still considers the year, and if I aply a filter for sorting it will not work since it is a query function. Any suggestion?

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(SORT(Sheet1!A2:Q27, TEXT(Sheet1!F2:F27, "mmdd")*1, 1), 
 "where Col6 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({
 QUERY(SORT({Sheet1!A2:Q27, TO_DATE(TEXT(Sheet1!F2:F27, "2222-mm-dd")*1)}, TEXT(Sheet1!F2:F27, "mmdd")*1, 1), 
 "where Col6 is not null and Col18 >= date '"&TEXT(DATE(2222, MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())), "e-m-d")&"'", 0);
 QUERY(SORT({Sheet1!A2:Q27, TO_DATE(TEXT(Sheet1!F2:F27, "2222-mm-dd")*1)}, TEXT(Sheet1!F2:F27, "mmdd")*1, 1), 
 "where Col6 is not null and Col18 < date '"&TEXT(DATE(2222, MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())), "e-m-d")&"'", 0)}, 9^9, 17))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! I managed to get the same result but by adding helper columns, this solved with no helper column and is a much better suit! the only issue that i still have is that i need to sort the columns, from the most recent birthday on top and the lasts go to the end, i tried to do this also by adding a helper column SELECT MONTH(F)-MONTH(TODAY()), it would create a column adding 0 to the current month and so on but for past months a negative value, and still cannot be used as a sorting column. Any thoughts on this it would be very much appreciated

Comment: @JesusNavarro by "most recent" you mean relative to today's date?

Comment: yes, ie, we are on April, therefore the sorting should start by April on top then May.. December, Jan, Fev, Mar.. that should be the order

Comment: @JesusNavarro answer updated

Comment: Amazing! Though I could not make sense of the formula to be honest, why are you using Col18 >= date when there is no Col18? just wondering :) but this totally did the job, and i am very much thankful for your help!

Comment: @JesusNavarro its because I added 18th column. you can see it if you change 17 to 18 at the end of the formula